# Format a column of ASPxGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress

So I got a ASPxGridView with few VisibleColumns which shows records of percentage value. I need for some of that columns, ie. VisibleColumns[1] , apply format of theirs value. These records are save in DB like 83.79000. These columns got rounded values in 2 decimal places.
So my first Question: how could i show these values in format like 83.79? 
Second Q: when  exactly I should do that? If you look at this code snippet, I guess after Databind i got a records in GridView but how modify them and save them to that GridView?

```
ASPxGridViewMain.DataSource = this.DataSource;
ASPxGridViewMain.DataBind();
```

Third Q: in purpose of Debugg, how i can see the values of that column?
EDIT: My ASPXGridView like:

```
<dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="TRS" VisibleIndex="1" Caption="Hodnota TRS">        
    </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`EditPropertiesBase.DisplayFormatString`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsEditPropertiesBase_DisplayFormatStringtopic) property to show values in your format. You don't need to modify your records. You can just add this to your `aspx` code:

```
<dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="TRS" VisibleIndex="1" Caption="Hodnota TRS">
    <PropertiesTextEdit DisplayFormatString="#.00" />
</dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

Comment: That exactly what i need. I am kind of shame that i didnt find out by my own. Thank you very much

Comment: I got one more question on you how can add a mark of % ? I tried "#.00%" or using p but it didnt works

Comment: @Alexander_Dracka If you use percentage placeholder (%) in your format string then you will see that your values are multiplied by 100. To avoid this behavior you must use the "\" escape character: `DisplayFormatString="#.00\%"`. You can get more info in [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN article.

Comment: Splendid. I will study that article for sure. Its good to know formating string. Thank you again . you have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

You should use `DataFormatString` the msdn link is below
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You should use bound fields to use data format.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="amount" HeaderText="amount"  
     ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="amount" DataFormatString="{0:n3}" />
```

### Edit 1

If you don't want to use `BoundField` then you should use [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of gridview. Get the cell and format as you like.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{   
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)  
    {  
        //get you cell here
        //put the number format here.
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bound columns in GridView and specify DataFormatString. Like below.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="C1" HeaderText="Display Column Name" DataFormatString="{0:0.00}"  />
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: thanks for your advice but I cant use it in <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="TRP" VisibleIndex="4" Caption="Hodnota TRP">        
        </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>